# Need a formula that turns $0.01 to of $0.00

Tags: salesforce

I have an issue where the price is showing $0.01 when it should be showing $0.00.

I found the custom field in question and wanted to create a formula that does something like the following.

```
If(value = $0.01, $0.00, value)
```

But I'm getting the following Error.

```
Error: Field $0.01 does not exist. Check spelling.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a dedicate site for Salesforce http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/  Apex code may be on topic here but a field formatting issue like this may be better on the Salesforce.SE site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As Michael comment you, salesforce.se may be faster site por this question.*

Anyhow, I think you need to user `ROUND(number, num_digits)`

More info in [the official doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm#ROUND).

Comment: +1 but I'd add a bit like "do not put $, € or thousand separators in formulas that work on currency fields, they're really stored as normal numbers". I wouldn't want to create a formula with such US mindset and later learn it fails for users with French locale ;)